# Allow function to accept array or tuple but force array literals to be treated as tuple in Flow

Tags: flowtype

I'm working on Flow types for a library that has a `getIn` function. This function takes an object and an array of keys and returns the value at the nested location within the object.

Right now I have it typed nicely with tuples like this:

```
declare function getIn<C, K1: $Keys<C>>(
  collection: C,
  keyPath: [K1]
): $ElementType<C, K1>;
declare function getIn<C, K1: $Keys<C>, K2: $Keys<$ElementType<C, K1>>>(
  collection: C,
  keyPath: [K1, K2],
): $ElementType<$ElementType<C, K1>, K2>;
// etc...
```

This correctly gets the correct type for a nested value and errors when there are mistakes in the passed keys like in these examples:

```
const data = { person: { name: 'Bobbie', friends: [] }};

// string
const correct = getIn(data, ['person', 'name']);

// Cannot call `getIn` because property `name2` (did you mean `name`?) is missing in object literal [1] in index 1. [incompatible-call]
const incorrect = getIn(data, ['person', 'name2']);
```

However I want to expand the types to allow for an array and return `mixed` (since this is a library and it should be valid to call it with an array even if we don't know the return type).

So I added another overload to the method:

```
declare function getIn(
  collection: mixed,
  keyPath: mixed[]
): mixed;
```

This makes it so that it accepts arrays, however this means that the type-checking when passing in an array literal no longer errors if the keys are incorrect, it just returns `mixed`. Here's an example:

```
// This used to error, but now it returns `mixed`.
const incorrect = getIn(data, ['person', 'name2']);
```

Is there a way to make it so that if I pass in an array literal it only uses the tuple overloads and not the array overload? I know that getting a `mixed` return type is better than nothing, but it would be awesome if I could get the advantages of both approaches instead of having to compromise.

Here's the [Flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMBJVAHgGEAaeAaQEYAueAEjpAE8BnKgPj4AKAFDx4YHBAjhseFjVHwA1lwAKUDAAsWAbUYBdYQEoWrAKLSAtiFQYAKpwAOIKrUZ8A3MNCRYCFOiy+ESkFDT0zGwcPPxuAEym0bzmVjb2Ti7h7gIiYhJSMrio8tSKKpzqWrqM8fqlJmwWINa2Ds7kKc1pbZluDHzxnsIA9MPwxGAAdNPe4NBwSGiYRYTEZLniktLLcvCWWAAeIMClYuWV2nuHxzqGDftHwF7CEqjcGPDAGlDwALzwAG94M4YNxdkDUFBrCwAOQAIRwACNEVgQDDaIgYKjUMBuLp9PAAL6E56jeDvLGoAgvPDvTYwOCYP6rUKCL4YKC0HQwkFg1Do+AwyHWGH6IyksYPY7wAC08BI8AA7lBbPAtFhuGqcOMGTgYDS3h8sOg9YyPv8Qut2Zz4NzeXgBUKoSA4qLxcIgA) with the above example.